# multiple chunks simultaneously pandas large data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, chunks

I am trying to concatenate and do manipulations with two extremely large (>800GiB) files using chunks.

Files looks as:

File1

```
1 1 0.5
1 2 0.2
2 2 0.4
2 3 0.2...
```

File2

```
1 1 0.6
1 2 0.3
2 2 0.6
2 3 0.7...
```

Result I want is file:

```
1 2 0.2 0.3
2 3 0.2 0.7...
```

I tried different chunk codes, but couldn't find option to: read 5000 records from both, proceed, save to file, and start with next 5000 from both.

Approx. code:

```
mode="w"
file1=pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delim_whitespace=True,header=None,chunksize=5000)
file2=pd.read_csv('test2.csv', delim_whitespace=True,header=None,chunksize=5000)
for chunk in file1:
   for chunk1 in file2:
     un_file1=chunk[chunk[0]!=chunk[1]]
     un_file2=chunk1[chunk1[0]!=chunk1[1]]
     conc=pd.concat([un_file2,un_file2[2]],axis=1)
     conc.to_csv(r'test_test.csv', header=False,index=False, sep=" ",mode=mode)
     mode="a"
```

So in current code all chunks from file 2 concatenated to first chunk of file 1 =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with iteratively reading one chunk from each of the files, then merging them:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', chunksize=1000)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', chunksize=1000)

while True:
    try:
        df1c = next(df1)
        df2c = next(df2)

        df1c = df1c[df1c['0'] != df1c['1']]
        df2c = df2c[df2c['0'] != df2c['1']]

        df1c.merge(df2c, on=['0', '1']).to_csv(
            'test3.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a')

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

It can still take a while though with files this size.

Comment: Yep, seems behaving well on test data. Will try on large one. Thank you.